# No smooth animation for processing sketch, yet normal GPU/CPU load and framerate

Tags: performance, processing, interactive

I'm working on the visualizations of an interactive installation as seen here: http://vimeo.com/78977964. But I'm running into some issues with the smoothness of the animation. While it tells me it runs on a steady 30 or 60 fps, the actual image is not smooth at all; imagine a 15fps animation with an unsteady clock. Can you guys give me some pointers on where to look in optimizing my sketch?

What I'm doing is receiving relative coordinates (0.-1. on x and y axis) through oscP5. This goes through a data handler to check if there hasn't been input in that area for x amount of time. If all is ok, a new *Wave* object is created, which will draw an expanding (modulated) circle on its location. As the installation had to be very flexible, all visual parameters are adjustable through a controlP5 GUI.

All of this is running on a computer with *i7 3770 3.4Ghz,8 GB RAm* and two *Radeon HD7700's* to drive 4 to 10 Panasonic EX600 XGA projectors over VGA (simply drawing a 3072x1536 window). The CPU and GPU load is reasonable ( http://imgur.com/a/usNVC ) but the performance is not what we want it to be.

We tried a number of solutions including: changing rendering mode; trying a different GPU; different drawing methods; changing process priority; exporting to application; etc. But nothing seemed to make a noticeable improvement. So now I'm guessing its either just processing/java not being able to run smoothly over multiple monitors or something is causing this in my code...

How I draw the waves within the wave class (this is called from the main draw loop for every wave object)

```
public void draw(){

this.diameter = map(this.frequency, lowLimitFrequency, highLimitFrequency, speedLowFreq, speedHighFreq) * (millis()-date)/5f;

strokeWeight(map(this.frequency, lowLimitFrequency, highLimitFrequency, lineThicknessLowFreq, lineThicknessHighFreq)*map(this.diameter, 0, this.maxDiameter, 1., 0.1)*50);

stroke(255,255,255, constrain((int)map(this.diameter, 0, this.maxDiameter, 255, 0),0,255));

pushMatrix();
beginShape();

translate(h*this.x*width, v*this.y*height);

//this draws a circle from line segments, and is modified by a sinewave
for (int i = 0;i<segments;i++) {

  vertex(
  (this.distortion*sin(map(i, 0, segments, 0, this.periods*TWO_PI))+1)* this.diameter*sin(i*TWO_PI/segments), 
  (this.distortion*sin(map(i, 0, segments, 0, this.periods*TWO_PI))+1)* this.diameter* cos(i*TWO_PI/segments)
    );
}
vertex(
(this.distortion*sin(map(0, 0, segments, 0, this.periods*TWO_PI))+1)* this.diameter*sin(0*TWO_PI/segments), 
(this.distortion*sin(map(0, 0, segments, 0, this.periods*TWO_PI))+1)* this.diameter* cos(0*TWO_PI/segments)
  );


endShape();
popMatrix();

}
```

I hope I've provided enough information to grasp whats going wrong!

Answer (score 1):

My colleagues and I have had similar issues here running a PowerWall (6x3 monitors) from one PC using an Eyefinity setup. The short version is that, as you've discovered, there are a lot of problems running Processing sketches across multiple cards.

We've tended to work around it by using a different approach - multiple copies of the application, which each span one monitor only, render a subsection and sync themselves up. This is the approach people tend to use when driving large displays from multiple machines, but it seems to sidestep these framerate problems as well.

For Processing, there're a couple of libraries that support this: Dan Shiffman's [Most Pixels Ever](https://github.com/shiffman/Most-Pixels-Ever-Processing) and the [Massive Pixel Environment](https://github.com/TACC/MassivePixelEnvironment) from the Texas Advanced Computing Center. They've both got reasonable examples that should help you through the setup phase.

One proviso though, we kept encountering crashes from JOGL if we tried this with OpenGL rendering - this was about 6 months ago, so maybe that's fixed now. Your draw loop looks like it'll be OK using Java2D, so hopefully that won't be an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. This confirms my suspicion that our issue is not something we can fix by simply optimizing the code. The plan of action for now is that we'll first try making a OpenFrameworks(C++) port (interesting to learn that language as well) and if it still gives us issues to go on to MPE.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this in the end? Was OpenFrameworks a better fit?

Comment: A very late response, but in the end we opted for using a Vioso system. This also allowed us to blend all the projected images together.